# Accessing DB2 in Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables, db2

I'm new to Linux operating system.

We have installed DB2 application under a user (test_user).  When I try to access the application from a newly created user (test_user2), db2 is not started.  It states this error.

```
DB21018E  (Failed to trigger db2 environment(DB21018E A system error occurred) from non-instance user)
```

However, when I try to access db2 from user (test_user1), it is working fine.

I read like the environment variables should be updated to point to correct PATH/LIBPATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  When I updated the variables and log off, the changes are gone in the next login.

These are my hurdles now.

1. How to make the DB2 accessible for test_user2
2. How to permanently update the env variables with correct path.

I tried reading many blogs to solve the problem but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blogs are often wrong because of their age. You need to carefully consider whether the blog is talking about the software versions you are using. You also don't seem to understand how environment variables work. They are private to each process and normally inherited from the parent process. If you want your env changes to persist you need to add those changes to an appropriate file such as *~/.bash_profile* or */etc/environment*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Db2 documentation for your version of Db2-LUW instead of using blogs.

For your question, study this [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=systems-setting-up-application-development-environment-linux-unix) ,

Each local linux user that wants to be able to run db2 commands needs to have the startup file of his/her shell configured to execute the correct `db2profile` for your Db2-instance.  This is a single line to add to the startup profile (e.g. .bashrc  or .profile, depending on which shell each user has).

If the shell chosen for test_user2 is bash, then edit the ~/.bashrc to add a line that looks something like `. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile` (where `db2inst1` is the name of your Db2-instance, i.e the userid that owns the process named `db2sysc`).

(A linux host can have more than one copy of Db2 running concurrently, with the same or different versions, each is an instance and has its own userid called the "instance owner").